# Why are there so many 与 here?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

In the following passage there are a lot of 与. Please let me know if I understand each of them correctly.

公关人是客户**与**市场受众的纽带， 公关公司职员通过**与**媒体编辑或记者的联系和沟通，将客户的需求软性地传递给目标客户群。

Public Relation are customers' **and** market audiences' link, PR companies' staff connects **with** media editor or reporters's connection and links(?), gathers customers' requests (and) softly/subtly reach out to the target market (?? please correct me)

在**与**客户的接洽方面，公关公司一般**与**客户公司的公关部或市场部接口，而他们往往对生活的**具象品质**质比较看重，在个人形象和品味方面会较为在意。

**With** (?? No idea what 在与 is) customers' side of the matter, PR companies usually connects **with** customer's company's PR division or marketing division, furthermore they quite care about life's **figurative product** (?? what is 具象品质?), fairly care about a person's image and interests (?)

By the way do people actually speak like like this in oral conversation?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

I am not commenting on your whole translation here, just the parts relating to 与.

As for the first passage, in the first case 与 is used to show that the link/connection is between the two items connected by 与 (literally it would read like: the A and B connection, i.e. the connection involving both A and B, which we say as between A and B).  As for the second case, we can analyze it as follows: [公关公司职员]通过[[与媒体编辑或记者]的联系和沟通]，[将[客户的需求]]软性地传递给[目标客户群] -> [the PR company's staff] through [[with media editors or reporters]'s relations and connections], [OBJ: [client's demands] gently convey to the target demographic] -> Through connecting with the media, the the PR company's staff gently conveys the client's demands to the target client base[?] (perhaps target demographic? I'm not 100% sure with business jargon).

在与客户的接洽方面 can be dissected as 在[与客户的接洽]方面 -> regarding/on/concerning discussions with customers.  As with the first passage, 与 is bringing together two items that are connected (in this case the two parties involved in the talks), only in this case the first item is omitted.  The next 与 is the same as described for the first passage (the interface between ... and ...)

as for 具象品质, the definition I found for 具象 has it as the opposite of 抽象, so perhaps: practical/effective product quality

Comment: Thank you! Based on your explanation would 公关公司职员通过与媒体编辑或记者的联系和沟通 translate better as "PR company's staff connects media editor's or reporter's connection with communication" ?

Comment: @rabbid, I have updated my answer to address your comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much. Seems so simple after you translate it, but it's quite hard for me to see what 与 connects when I first read it :) I really like your usage of the brackets by the way. It's very clear!